# Programmatically save open document in MS Word Add-In

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-addins

I'm trying to create an add-in in C# for MS Word 2010 that will add a new ribbon and a click event-handler. This click event-handler should save the active file in `c:\temp`,  for example. And then I need to load the file content into a byte array.

Probably something like this:

```
public void ClickEventHandler(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    string fileLocation = "c:\temp\test.docx";
    Word.Document document = this.Document;
    document.SaveAs(fileLocation);
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocation);
}
```

The point is, this is pseudo-code and I don't know how to load an active document into a byte array. If there is a way without saving the document it would be even better.

And a query if the active file is a docx (and not a doc file) would be nice as well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, by the way? Welcome to StackOverlow! :)

Comment: Well thank you. i'm new into programming and i'm just testing. i try to convert a docx document into a xhtml file and i'm using this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628051%28v=office.14%29.aspx and well, it's working but i would like to implement this feature in an word 2010 add-in. problem is, i can't convert a document, which is currently opened in word.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want to do is possible. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Word.Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;     
document.SaveAs2(goldenpath + "\\" + name + "." + id + ".docx");
document.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this generic function in my program to serialize arbitrary objects to a byte array:

```
private byte[] MakeByteSize<U>(U obj)
{
  if (obj == null) return null;

  var bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
  var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

**Edit:**

After reading your additional content, I'm confident that serializing the `Word.Document` object won't get you what you need, since the byte array representing that object in the program (which is probably a wrapper around some COM interop) won't be the same as the byte array representing the information stored in the file about the document.

Looking at the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628051%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you referenced, it looks like what we really need is a `WordprocessingDoc` instance representing the document that we can pass to the `HtmlConverter` class. So I think the question you really want to ask is "How can I create a `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument` from an open document without saving the file first?"

Unforunately, I'm not sure that's possible since I'm not really spotting any [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument_members.aspx) on that [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.aspx) that would do that.

On the `.doc` vs `.docx` issue, the [Open XML SDK for Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28v=office.14%29.aspx) says that it works with documentat that adhere to the "Office Open XML File Formats Specification" which I believe means it will only work with the `.docx` file format. You might have to try a different route on this, like exporting to PDF perhaps. Good luck!